# How to Use Universal image Loader for add apps icon on Imageview?

Tags: android

```
Drawable drawable = mInfo.loadIcon(mContext.getPackageManager());
holder.imagev.setImageDrawable(item.getIcon());  // Using ImageLoader
```

I have to Use here ImageLoader instead of SetImageDrawable any help pls

Comment: Go through this link http://javatechig.com/android/universal-image-loader-library-in-android

Comment: yaa tnx I Did that before but i wnt to know that any other lib to do this possible or any hint to solve this @AnshumanBorah

Comment: @SunilChaudhary Why you want to use the Image Loader here i cant find the any thing that you required to use the image loader library

Comment: i want to get all Apps icons , if I'm not using UIL it Slowing down my gridview , but in UIL it save icons in cache thats why i want to use it  @Sandy.

Comment: @SunilChaudhary check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the url for drawable like this

```
String url = "drawable://" + R.drawable.yourdrawablename;
```

Now use like this

```
imageloader.displayImage(url, imageView, options);
```

hope this help.

Let me know in case of issue

Answer (score 0):

Done without Using Universal ImageLoader now work Smooth, Check this line

Utilities.createIconThumbnail(info.icon, getContext()); //Check this Method on below link

and  [This Link](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_launcher/blob/master/src/com/android/launcher/ApplicationsAdapter.java)